# Save Web Service Response as XML

Tags: testing, hp-uft, web-api-testing

I'm working with HP UFT nad HP ALM. I'm trying to save a web service response as xml in an **API-Test**. I found many tutorials to save a response in an Excel but it's not what I want.

Is this possible? If not, is it possible to download an .wsdl response?

**API-Test construction**

1. Control if there exist an specific xml file(refernce.xml) on my computer
2. If not then stop the test/if the reference.xml exist then keep going
3. Now I want to save the response
4. Compare the 2 files(reference.xml and downloaded xml)

Comment: @dmcgill50 i'm sorry! After i asked this question i found the solution. 
A happy coincidence:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Api Tests/Components you can do this by simply using the standard activities available.

In the Toolbox menu, under 'Standard Activities' expand the 'File' list and add the 'Write to File' activity to your flow. Then, in the Input/Checkpoints tab of the activity you can set the export path (in the path you should include the name.xml file that will be generated) and the content (for the content you can select the main tag of the response, that holds all the content :  for example).

[image]

https://community.hpe.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing/UFT-API-Save-Response-as-xml/td-p/6867566

Comment: Because it's you;)

Comment: Thanks @david-schor ! Davids have to stick together!

Answer (score 0):

In Api Tests/Components you can do this by simply using the standard activities available.

In the Toolbox menu, under 'Standard Activities' expand the 'File' list and add the 'Write to File' activity to your flow. Then, in the Input/Checkpoints tab of the activity you can set the export path (in the path you should include the `name.xml file that will be generated) and the content (for the content you can select the main tag of the response, that holds all the content:`` for example).

*Source: https://community.hpe.com*.